# Create dataframe from a dict with specific dtypes, in particular Nullable IntegerArray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

def create_response_dataframe(response):

    d = { }

    for index, item in response.items() :

        d[int(index)] = \
            {
                "name"      : item.get("name", None),  #str or None
                "surname"   : item.get("surname", None), #str or None
                "age"       : item.get("age", None) # int or None
            }

    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")


def join_response_to_dataframe(df, response):

    response_df = create_response_dataframe(response)
    df = df.join(response_df, how="left", sort=False)

    return df
```

After doing some calculations, I end up with a dictionary of results that I want to join back to an existing dataframe. However, because some of the integer values are missing in the dictionary (value == None) pandas stores these as NaN, changes the dtype to float and converts my integer age values to float.

The columns that contain strings happily co-exist with NaN values.

I want to keep my values as integers, and avoid wasting time on the conversion in the first place, as I typically will have millions of rows.

I came across the [Nullable Integer Data Type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#integer-na) in pandas 0.24.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to force the dtype of the age column to "Int64"? What
   would be the recommended method?
2. Should I create each column in the response as a Series with the
   same index and an explicit dtype and add them to the dataframe
   individually? Should I expect an significant performance difference
   compared to DataFrame.from_dict() and df.join()?

Comment: Depending on what you do after, what about assigning let say `-1` instead of `None` in the column age for missing data, like this, you still have integers, and you know where the missing value for the age are?

Comment: That's works pretty well for most cases I think. In the few where it won't I'll go with creating a Series for now.